# Is there any event or function in office 365 add-in which should be executed without opening the add-in?

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to send a request on server after some interval but the request is going after opening the add-in when I implement my logic in .js File of my add-in. Is there any method or event which will trigger my logic after some interval without opening the add-in, the thing which i want is just install the add-in and it should start work like the desktop add-in of outlook in which we have a method of start_up in ThisAddIn.cs
please help.